# Microwave rice cooker vs low-end electric rice cookers

Tags: rice, rice-cooker

So, at my parents home we had a two part microwave rice cooker which created relatively dry rice in my experience (though I only used it myself a couple of time), but I actually like it better than traditionally boiled rice on a stove (which in my experience turns out quite wet-ish no matter how you make it).  Now, I am not a huge fan of rice either way, so I am not planning on investing much into a rice cooker, but I was wondering what advantages a low end electric rice cooker would give as all comparisons I was able to find were comparing electric rice cookers to traditional boiling methods.

Comment: PS. To keep the question generic I didn't include a semi-answer, but what I have deduced myself is that electric rice cookers have a keep-warm function and that they might (!) be easier to keep clean?

Answer (score 1):

I never used a microwave rice cooker but if you are getting dry rice then it's a matter of the amount of water used. The same goes for electric rice cooker, if you don't like wet-ish rice then use less water.

The main drawback of the microwave cooker is you can't use the microwave while making your rice.

Electric rice cooker can keep warm, you can turn it on and come back the next morning if you want to (a decent model). 
Some have time counters, clocks and other similar features.
The rice never sticks since it is a non-stick pan.
You can most likely make more rice with a rice cooker than the microwave container (googled an image).

Also when you have guests, some people might not like the idea of rice made in a microwave even though it might taste and look the same. Some rice cookers also comes with steam baskets so when cooking the rice you can steam veggies at the same time. A rice cooker can also be used to cook other stuff as well.

Comment: I might be doing something really wrong, but creating dry rice when boiling it without making a huge mess at the bottom has eluded my skills for ages. But fair enough, you covered a couple of points I hadn't noticed before, so that's nice to keep in mind. And honestly, you're right about a stigma against microwaves... so weird actually.